# Javascript Calculator - How to efficiently program buttons with same class without errors?

Tags: javascript, calculator

I keep getting 'undefined' or errors and I'm not quite sure why.

I'm trying to click multiple keys with the same class but different values using one function. What must I understand to accomplish this task?

```
let keys = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");

let displayScreen = document.getElementById("display");

function display() {
    displayScreen.innerText += keys.value;
}

display();
```

or

```
keys.onclick = () => {
   displayScreen.innerText += keys.value;
}

    <div class="row">
        <div class="column display" id="display"></div>
    </div>      

    <div class="row">
        <div class="keys" id="six" value="6">6</div>
        <div class="keys" id="five" value="5">5</div>
        <div class="keys" id="four" value="4">4</div>
        <div class="keys" id="minus" value="-">-</div>
    </div>
```

I've seen[objectHTML divELEMENT...], 'undefined' and some times I get red error in the console.log and sometimes I get nothing at all and I'd like to know why?

I understand the results or errors may stem from improper syntax amongst other factors but again what must I understand about javascript in order to minimize this issue?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question seems like an exercise in debugging. Take a look at [How to debug small programs]( https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<div>`s should not have a `.value` property - that's reserved for input-like elements. But you can extract the `textContent` of the clicked element element, and you can use event delegation to avoid adding tons of listeners:

```js
const displayScreen = document.getElementById("display");
document.querySelector('.num-keys').addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  if (!target.matches('.num-keys > div')) {
    return;
  }
  displayScreen.textContent += target.textContent;
});
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column display" id="display">[display] </div>
</div>

<div class="num-keys">
  <div>6</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>-</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks!